# Insert records in JDBC without using insert statement

Tags: mysql, jdbc, sql-insert

I am particularly new to the concept of accessing Databases in Java using JDBC. I am using MySql as my DBMS and I just wanted to know whether there is a way to insert records in my Database without using the "insert" statement of MySql?

Comment: Why? Please explain why you don't want to use `INSERT`. Is it just academic curiosity, or do you have some sort of dislike for `INSERT`?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel The former one i.e. Academic Curiosity

Answer (score 1):

Looking purely at JDBC, it is possible to add new rows into a database without using an `INSERT` yourself. However there is no guarantee that the actual JDBC driver doesn't use an `INSERT` statement.

```java
try (
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(....);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
        ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM someTable");
) {
    rs.moveToInsertRow();
    rs.updateString(1, "new value col1");
    rs.updateString(2, "new value col2");
    rs.updateString(3, "new value col3");
    rs.insertRow();
}
```

This will insert a row through the result set, but the actual implementation might simply generate an `INSERT` statement to achieve this. Also this way isn't very efficient (especially if the table has a a large number of rows), and it might fail if we haven't selected (or updated) columns that have constraints (for example a `NOT NULL` or a `CHECK` constraint).

There are also a number of frameworks built on top of JDBC that allow you to create and manipulate data without having to write queries yourself, however in the end chance are that it will generate an `INSERT` queries.

So: from your perspective yes it is certainly possible to insert data into the database, but in the end the tool you use to do that will probably use `INSERT` statements in some form.

Comment: Can CallableStatement be used in any way to perform the required action?

Comment: @VishalChugh Not really, it is for executing stored procedures. So if you have a stored procedure that does inserts for you, then yes, but that is still is a form of 'cheating' (as the stored procedure itself will contain insert statements).